# flutter SliverAppBar FlexibleSpaceBar can't detect when i enable accessibility

Tags: flutter, accessibility, sliverappbar

the content in flexibleSpace in SliverAppBar can't detect when I enable accessibility.

I try this sample
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlexibleSpaceBar-class.html